# Is there a programming language for contests?

Tags: programming-languages

Is there a programming language that measures everything?

For instance, I would like to measure how much memory was allocated, the number of operations used (in terms of cycles), and time spent on IO.

Such a language would be great for running a programming contest.

Comment: Would any participant then have to learn your weird contest-language to participate? You can just ask the OS about these things.

Comment: Tooling exists to do that for a number of existing languages. These tools are collectively known as [profilers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider running a program compiled/interpreted by an existing language under a tool like ValGrind, which can report on these kinds of factors.  You could extend ValGrind further if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want a *tool*, not necessarily a language.  I use profiling tools to do these sorts of things with embedded C programs.  Your compiler vendor may have similar tools available.

The OS is in charge of memory management, so it's probably easiest to get the OS to report that to you.  Another option is to write a library that entrants are required to use that builds wrappers around `malloc`, etc.  When the library's `malloc` is called, it logs how much memory was allocated and calls the real `malloc`.  Once the program terminates, you have a complete log of the dynamic memory usage of the program.  You can also write wrappers around I/O functions that log the latency of those functions (take a timestamp before calling the real function and after it completes).